# How to use ng-if with input textbox alongwith ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angular-ng-if

I am using angularjs.

In my html I have 2 input boxes

```
edit = false;

<input type="text" value=""  data-ng-if="edit" ng-model="name">
<input type="text" value="" data-ng-if="!edit" ng-model="singleAppDetails.name">
```

so here I wanted to show only one input box at a time based on some condition.
But i guess ng-if is not working.Basically if **edit == true** i want to show **singleAppDetails.name** and if **edit == false** then **name**

Comment: Did you try `data-ng-if="edit==true"` ??

Comment: is 'edit' a scope variable? So to say: is $scope.edit declared?

Comment: Where have you declared `edit`? In your controller? If so, make it `$scope.edit = false;`

Comment: It's confusing having `edit = false;` in the same code section as your html, put some text like `html:` at the start of a line between to separate them.  Also, what exactly is happening?  You say `ng-if` isn't working, does that mean both of them are showing?  If so, check your console for errors.  Some error probably crashed angular or it isn't running.  Enter `<p>edit: {{edit}}</p>` before the text boxes to check that the value is set correctly and angular is binding.

Answer (score 1):

HTML DOM:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="testController">
        <input type="text" value=""  data-ng-if="edit" ng-model="name">
        <input type="text" value="" data-ng-if="!edit" ng-model="singleAppDetails.name">
    </div>
</div>
```

Angularjs:

```
   angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller("testController", function($scope){
      $scope.singleAppDetails = {
        "name" : "name if not editable"
      }
      $scope.name = "name if editable";
      $scope.edit = false;
    })
```

example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqKQJO

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
<input type="text" value=""  data-ng-if="edit" ng-model="(edit ? name : singleAppDetails.name)">
```

This way you only use an input to cover both cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-switch="edit">
    <div ng-switch-when='false'>
       <input type="text" value="" ng-model="singleAppDetails.name">
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when='true'>
       <input type="text" value="" ng-model="name">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used this technique but while posting the using POST method. it is sending null value for parameters.